# Class gets added, but has no affect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a project and have run into a little sticking point on adding a class, but having that class not take affect.

```
$('.anchor-list > li').addClass('anchor-list-fade');
```

Here is the base class for the element:

```
.anchor-list > li
{
    background: rgba(50, 57, 98, 1);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: none;
}
```

Here is the class that gets added:

```
.anchor-list-fade
{
    background: rgba(50, 57, 98, 0.4);
}
```

The ultimate goal is to have those elements "fade" by changing their alpha value when a certain element is clicked. On clicking V0 in the example (click an F to see the V) http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/899dv/ I can examine the F item's parent (the list element) in Firebug and see this, the added class with a strikethrough indicating that some other style is taking preference and the style that *is* taking preference:

```
.anchor-list > li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(50, 57, 98, 1);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

.anchor-list-fade {
    <s>`background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(50, 57, 98, 0.4);`</s>}

I feel like I am missing something obvious here, but I have been trying several things to correct this to no avail. Why doesn't the added class take affect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your second selector is less specific. See  http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ That is, when there are conflicting rules, the engine uses the one with more components by order of specificity: id, class, tagname. (**Warning** this is a simplification, go to the link for further details)

Your first selector has a class and a tag, your second selector only has a class. The first one wins.

The following would work

```
.anchor-list > li.anchor-list-fade
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and the solution. It makes perfect sense now that I read it. Appreciate it!

Comment: @JayBlanchard I forgot about the timer... There are plenty of people that forget to accept answers, it's Mendes by the way